# ASP.NET MVC Identity default controllers and views not being generated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Identity. The steps that I follow to do this are:

(1) File > New > Project
(2) ASP.NET Core Web Application > OK
(3) Web Application (Model-View-Controller) > Change authentication > Individual User Accounts
(4) OK > OK

Visual Studio is supposed to generate Account, Home, and Manage controllers, as well as Account, Home, and Manage view folders and views. However, it's not doing this. What do I need to do to have it generate these items?

I've tried upgrading my SDK to 2.2.107.

[image]

Comment: The template will not create them if you don’t set the authentication process. It’s on this screen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started/_static/image3.png

Comment: That's a really old screen shot. It doesn't look like that in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: No, that is VS2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: It seems to work for .NET Framework, but I want to do it for .NET Core.

Comment: Looks like they are doing this in a package now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my original post, but I tried downloading the AspNetCore.Identity package through NuGet, but doing this doesn't generate the controllers or view folders or views I mentioned.

Comment: It doesn’t generate them.  They register them for you.  A lot of packages do this.